# Julia equivalent of dplyr's bind_cols and bind_rows

Tags: r, dplyr, julia

Is there a Julia equivalent of dplyr's bind_cols and bind_rows? Specifically, I'm looking for a bind_rows function which will match column names regardless of order and fill in NA's for non-matching columns

Edit: R Example of both:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = data.frame(a = 1, b = 1)
df2 = data.frame(b = 1, c = 1)
df3 = data.frame(c = 1, d = 1)

bind_rows(df1, df2)

   a b  c
1  1 1 NA
2 NA 1  1

bind_cols(df1, df3)

  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Would one of the [`join` functions](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/joins_and_indexing.html) satisfy your requirements (`kind = :outer` ?)?

Comment: I suppose join with kind = :outer followed by a subset such that the row id's match could substitute for bind_cols. But it's a little inelegant. And I'm more interested in bind_rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps Julia's `vcat` and `hcat` functions will satisfy your requirements.

#### Code for DataFrames.jl 1.4.4

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df1 = DataFrame(a = 1, b = 1)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      1

julia> df2 = DataFrame(b = 1, c = 1)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ b      c
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      1

julia> df3 = DataFrame(c = 1, d = 1)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ c      d
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      1

julia> vcat(df1, df2, cols=:union)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b      c
     │ Int64?   Int64  Int64?
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │       1      1  missing
   2 │ missing      1        1

julia> hcat(df1, df3)
1×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      d
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      1      1
```

#### OLD ANSWER

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df1 = DataFrame(a = 1, b = 1)
1x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | a | b |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 1 |

julia> df2 = DataFrame(b = 1, c = 1)
1x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | b | c |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 1 |

julia> df3 = DataFrame(c = 1, d = 1)
1x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | c | d |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 1 |

julia> vcat(df1, df2)
2x3 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | a  | b | c  |
|-----|----|---|----|
| 1   | 1  | 1 | NA |
| 2   | NA | 1 | 1  |

julia> hcat(df1, df3)
1x4 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | a | b | c | d |
|-----|---|---|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```