# ArgumentError: column(s) c are missing from argument(s) 1, and column(s) a are missing from argument(s) 2

Tags: dataframe, join, julia

I would like to row bind two dataframes with different columns like `bind_rows` in R. I tried the same with `vcat` as in this question: [Julia equivalent of dplyr's bind_cols and bind_rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562368/julia-equivalent-of-dplyrs-bind-cols-and-bind-rows), but I get an error. Here some reproducible code:

```
using DataFrames

df1 = DataFrame(a = 1, b = 1)
df2 = DataFrame(b = 1, c = 1)
vcat(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
ArgumentError: column(s) c are missing from argument(s) 1, and column(s) a are missing from argument(s) 2
```

I don't know why this error happens, because in the answer of the question it does work. So I was wondering if anyone knows why this error happens and if this is the best way to bind two dataframes in Julia?

Comment: The original question is from 2015 so it is very outdated. I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because those DataFrames have columns with different names (technically, properties). Use the `cols=:union` keyword argument:

```
vcat(df1, df2, cols=:union)
# 2×3 DataFrame
#  Row │ a        b      c
#      │ Int64?   Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼─────────────────────────
#    1 │       1      1  missing
#    2 │ missing      1        1
```

`union` holds a union of columns. `cols` have more options. check them out [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.vcat) if you are interested.